# Junção de buscas Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho a função no meu controller:

```
public function pesquisa(Request $request)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('celular')) {
            return abort(401);
        }

        $marcas = CelularMarca::orderBy('nome', 'asc')->pluck('nome','id')->all();
        $modelos = CelularModelo::orderBy('nome', 'asc')->pluck('nome','id')->all();
        $cores = Cor::orderBy('nome', 'asc')->pluck('nome','id')->all();
        $cidades = Cidade::orderBy('nome', 'asc')->pluck('nome','id')->all();
        $situacoes = CelularSituacao::orderBy('nome', 'asc')->pluck('nome','id')->all();

        $buscar_marca = $request['marca_id'];
        $buscar_modelo = $request['modelo_id'];
        $buscar_cor = $request['cor_id'];
        $buscar_cidade = $request['cidade_id'];
        $buscar_data_inicial = $request['data_inicial'];
        $buscar_data_final = $request['data_final'];
        $buscar_bou = $request['bou'];
        $buscar_imei1 = $request['imei1'];
        $buscar_situacao = $request['situacao_id'];

        // cria o array que será utilizado no query builder
        $buscar_todos;
        $buscar_datas;

        // verifica se buscou marca
        if($buscar_marca) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['marca_id', $buscar_marca];
        }

        // verifica se buscou modelo
        if($buscar_modelo) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['modelo_id', 'like', '%'.$buscar_modelo.'%'];
        }

        // verifica se buscou cor
        if($buscar_cor) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['cor_id', $buscar_cor];
        }  

        // verifica se buscou cidade
        if($buscar_cidade) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['cidade_id', $buscar_cidade];
        }   

        // verifica se buscou data
        if($buscar_data_inicial) {
            $buscar_datas[] = ['data_inicial', $buscar_data_inicial];
        }  

        // verifica se buscou data
        if($buscar_data_final) {
            $buscar_datas[] = ['data_inicial', $buscar_data_final];
        }         

        // verifica se buscou BOU
        if($buscar_bou) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['bou', $buscar_bou];
        }

        // verifica se buscou IMEI1
        if($buscar_imei1) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['imei1', 'like', '%'.$buscar_imei1.'%'];
        }

        // verifica se buscou situação
        if($buscar_situacao) {
            $buscar_todos[] = ['situacao_id', $buscar_situacao];
        }

       // verifica se há valores para utilizar no 'where'
        if(isset($buscar_todos)){
            $celulares = Celular::where($buscar_todos)->get();
        } 

        if(isset($buscar_datas)){
            $celulares = Celular::whereBetween('data',[$buscar_data_inicial, $buscar_data_final])->get();
        } 


        else{
            $celulares = Celular::all();
        } 

        return view('celulares.pesquisa', compact('celulares','marcas','modelos','cores','cidades','situacoes'));
    }
```

Porém não estou conseguindo juntar os campos de pesquisa junto com as datas, ou pesquisa os campos ou apenas as datas, gostaria de saber como posso resolver isso na função.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com uma série de if e elseinf, não sei se a maneira mais elegante, porém deu certo, segue o código:

```
// verifica se há valores para utilizar no 'where'
        if(isset($buscar_todos, $buscar_data_inicial, $buscar_data_final)){  
            $celulares = Celular::where($buscar_todos)
            ->whereBetween('data',[$buscar_data_inicial, $buscar_data_final])
            ->get();
        }

        elseif(isset($buscar_todos, $buscar_data_inicial)){  
            $celulares = Celular::where($buscar_todos)
            ->whereBetween('data',[$buscar_data_inicial, date('Y-m-d')])
            ->get();
        }

        elseif(isset($buscar_todos, $buscar_data_final)){  
            $celulares = Celular::where($buscar_todos)
            ->where('data','<=',$buscar_data_final)
            ->get();
        }

        elseif (isset($buscar_todos)) {
            $celulares = Celular::where($buscar_todos)
            ->get();
        } 

        elseif (isset($buscar_data_inicial, $buscar_data_final)) {
            $celulares = Celular::whereBetween('data',[$buscar_data_inicial, $buscar_data_final])
            ->get();
        }

        elseif (isset($buscar_data_inicial)) {
            $celulares = Celular::whereBetween('data',[$buscar_data_inicial, date('Y-m-d')])
            ->get();
        } 

        elseif (isset($buscar_data_final)) {
            $celulares = Celular::where('data','<=',$buscar_data_final) 
            ->get();
        } 

        else{
            $celulares = Celular::all();
        }
```